# Semantic HTML5 and proper use of tags

Tags: html5

I'm trying to develop a base for a blog using some of the new tags introduced in HTML5 and I want to not only make sure I'm using them correctly, but my code is also semantic.

Here is just the *'sample'* document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>page title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <header>
        <hgroup>
            <h1>Blog title</h1>
            <h2>Blog tagline goes here</h2>
        </hgroup>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#top-level-link">Top Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#top-level-link">Top Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#top-level-link">Top Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <!-- <hr> commenting out so the answers still make sense -->
    <aside>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">sidebar link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sidebar link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sidebar link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </aside>
    <div class="content">
        <article>
            <h3>Article Header</h3>
            <section>
                <h4>Section header</h4>
                <p>Article section content</p>
            </section>
            <section>
                <h4>Section header</h4>
                <p>Article section content</p>
            </section>
            <section>
                <h4>Section header</h4>
                <p>Article section content</p>
            </section>
            <footer>
            posted by <a rel="author" href="#">user</a> on <time datetime="2012-01-01T00:00+00:00">January 1st, 2012. 12:00pm</time>
            </footer>
        </article>
        <article>
            <h3>Article Header</h3>
            <section>
                <h4>Section header</h4>
                <p>Article section content</p>
            </section>
                    <!-- more sections may exist per article -->
            <footer>
            posted by <a rel="author" href="#">user</a> on <time datetime="2012-01-01T00:00+00:00">January 1st, 2012. 12:00pm</time>
            </footer>
        </article>
        <article>
            <h3>Article Header</h3>
            <section>
                <h4>Section header</h4>
                <p>Article section content</p>
            </section>
                    <!-- more sections may exist per article -->
            <footer>
            posted by <a rel="author" href="#">user</a> on <time datetime="2012-01-01T00:00+00:00">January 1st, 2012. 12:00pm</time>
            </footer>
        </article>
    </div>
    <!-- <hr> Don't wanna make these guys look crazy -->
    <footer>
    Page footer.
    </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone see any misuse of the new tags or any better - cleaner way to write this?

Comment: Also, `<meta charset="utf-8">`. It's probably simpler.

Comment: lol probably. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Quick review:

- Remove this damn `<hr>`, styling is for CSS.
- In each `<section>`, you better have an `<h2>` :-)
- You can add `rel="author"` to your `<a>` link on the author. Even better, you can use `<a href="https://url.to.google.plus/user?rel=author" rel="author">The author's name</a>` (Google will recognize this as a "rich snippet" and show your face in google results. Take a look at http://schema.org for more information). Rich snippets are a whole other topic, so I'll stop talking about it :)

Edit after your comment:

- Each article should contain an `<h2>` for its article sections.
- Each article should have its title in an `<h1>`. Yes, even if there are multiple `<h1>` in the main page. If there is just the titles on the main page (no article's text), feel free to use `<h2>`.
- The `<h1>` on the frontpage is tolerated, not on the blog pages. Feel free to use it or not on the frontpage, but make sure that each blog page has the title of the post as an `<h1>`, not the site's name.

Related picture:

[image: flowchart]

Comment: Primary headers in the page, `<article>`s, and `<sections>` should use `<h1>` elements. If the region has a secondary header `<h2>` should be used.

Comment: @zzzzBov even though semantic html is nice, we also can't forget about SEO. That's why using H1 elements everywhere is often not an option (or rather, not the *best* option).

Comment: @FlorianMargaine, the question was about semantic HTML, and not optimizing for search engines. Besides, google's (not worth pretending that anyone uses a different search engine) algorithms follow common web practices, and are adapting to support HTML5.

Comment: @zzzzBov still, it is real life :-)

Comment: @FlorianMargaine, your right, life is real, and this *is* a blog format. SEO lost/gained from use of `h1` elements is negligible in comparison to the gains from people sharing links to the page. More important to emphasize the quality of the content over the structure of the markup.

Comment: To satisfy both of you; the question is first and foremost about semantic html and using the new html5 tags properly. This does however entail optimizing them for SEO (where it still conforms with the semantic parts).

Comment: "Remove this damn `<hr>`" ... Not even self-closed or anything.

Answer (score 7):

In my opinion for the most part, that looks good. However, there are a few small things I would question.

- Do you really need the wrapper `div` element? I would remove it so you have the `header` as the first child of the `body`.
- I would probably get rid of the `section` elements of each `article`. While their use is probably semantically valid, I think just the `p` elements would suffice.
- The contents of the `time` elements currently causes your document not to validate. See the [relevant part of the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20100624/text-level-semantics.html#the-time-element) for more details. Here's the error from the [validator](http://validator.w3.org/):

  > The text content of element time was not in the required format: The
  >   literal did not satisfy the date or time format.

**Update**

- The `hr` element is not semantically valid in the way you have used it. It could be replaced with CSS targeting the page `header` and `footer`. [From the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20100624/grouping-content.html#the-hr-element) (emphasis added):

  > The `hr` element represents a **paragraph-level thematic break**, e.g. a
  >   scene change in a story, or a transition to another topic within a
  >   section of a reference book.

Comment: I gave him the same answer about `section` in `article` tags. Then after reading the specs and some posts about that, it seems that for big articles, `section` is really appropriate to subdivide a blog post, and then add `header`, `headings` and `footer` to every `section`

Comment: Ahh I also misread the `TIME` tag spec... Adding `datetime` attribute (with a valid value) will correct the validator errors. Thanks:)

Comment: ahh also did not know that about the `HR` element..

Comment: @DieVarDump - I'm not sure that each `section` in this case would need a `header` and `footer`, hence the suggestion to remove the `section` elements. I'm not entirely sure on that point though.

Comment: I think having a header is probably prudent... but a footer may not be needed for each section. (but this should be reviewed per article basis... not every article will need more than one section.)